# how to get input from console in Xcode 4 in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, arguments

i want to run project in xcode but i can not get input from console i have checked websites but i can't get it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

cout<<"\n"<<argc<<"\n";
```

i am getting the ouput as 1 but i don't know how to get input from the console

output that i am getting is

GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
[Switching to process 8492 thread 0x0]

1
Program ended with exit code: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argc` is not "input from the console", it's the number of arguments passed to your program on the command line (and those arguments are contained in `argv`).

If you want to get input from the console, you would need to read from standard in (`std::cin`)

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: thats right but argc is 1. i want to enter some value to it but at the time of compiling console does not require arguments
cin is for input from console but i want to do it like this ./a.out 2 34 45 here argc will be 2 and argv will be 34 and 45

Comment: You can't "enter some value into it". It's the number of arguments. If you give your program arguments, it will reflect the number of them. In the example you just gave, `argc` would be `4` (the first element in `argv` is the program name) and `argv` will be 2,34,45

Comment: thats what i am talking i want to give program arguments only

Answer (score 1):

To get input from console, use std::cin:

```
int main() 
{
    cout << "please input: ";
    std::string str;
    while(str!= "quit")
    {
        cin >> str;
        cout<< "your input is : " << str <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on the other answer it sounds like you're actually asking how to enter program arguments, not console input. If you want `argc` to be a different number you have to give the program some arguments. You can do that in the options window for the scheme you're using. Find the Edit Scheme menu item and enter some arguments for your program.

Comment: thanks for the answer 

so now each time we have to set the arguments from cmd+< this seems lots of work

Comment: my console window disappear after some run is there any way to pop out the console window

Comment: You can change the behaviors to make it not disappear (I think it's in the menu Xcode > Edit Behaviors), or you can just open the console window up again using the toolbar (there's a button for displaying the bottom pane), or you can use the navigator to view any previous session. You can also pop it out into a separate window by creating a tab, making the console view fill that tab, and then drag the tab out of the xcode window, but I don't think that's the best way.

Comment: Yes, changing the command line arguments is not as easy as when you run programs from the command line. Usually IDEs don't expect that you'll be changing arguments much. Visual Studio has a similar problem. However Xcode does have a nice feature; you can enter a whole bunch of command line arguments as a single item in the argument list, and then you can use each item in the list as a different set of arguments, which you select between using the checkboxes. This way, if you have a few different argument sets you want to switch between you can save them all and switch just with the checkboxes.